# How to refer to a JavaScript tooltip in Watir

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir

I trying to automate hovering over a tooltip and verify the text in the span class. My code returns true but it gives me a blank statement. My tooltip is written in JavaScript if that helps. `# puts $browser.div(:class, 'device_info').p(:class, 'gridfield_tooltip').span(:class, 'title_text').text`

Here is the html

[image]

Comment: I've edited your question to change "Java" to "JavaScript." They are not the same thing and the terms cannot be used interchangeably. As a cleverer person than me once said, Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster.

Answer (score 1):

I end up using this:

```
device_name = $browser.div(:class, 'device_info').div.span(:id, 'FriendlyName').a
device_name.hover 
tooltip = $browser.div(:class, 'device_info').span(:class, 'tooltip_init')
tooltip.hover 
title_text = $browser.div(:class, 'device_info').p(:class, 'gridfield_tooltip').span(:class, 'title_text')
puts title_text.when_present.text
```

It only prints one line.

Answer (score 0):

The `text` method only returns currently visible text. An empty string will occur when the element is not visible.

Since this is a tooltip, you need to:

- Trigger the tooltip to appear and
- Depending on the implementation, wait for the tooltip to appear (as it is possible that Watir will check the element text before the tooltip finishes being displayed)

This can be accomplished with the `hover` and `when_present` methods:

```
e = $browser.div(:class, 'device_info').p(:class, 'gridfield_tooltip').span(:class, 'title_text')
e.hover
e.when_present.text
```

If you are only interested in checking the text and not the tooltip functionality itself, you could check the element's inner HTML instead. This would return the title text regardless of whether or not the element is visible.

```
e = $browser.div(:class, 'device_info').p(:class, 'gridfield_tooltip').span(:class, 'title_text')
e.inner_html
```

Comment: The only way for the tooltip to be visible is if you hover over it. I tried a <code> e = $browser.div(:class, 'device_info').p(:class, 'gridfield_tooltip').span(:class, 'title_text').hover e.when_present.text </code> and it did work

Comment: Ah sorry. I assumed you had the code for making the tooltip display.